# Limitations of programmatically setting phone calls

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call, ios9.1

Is there a way of programmatically setting an app so that it lets you automatically reject all phone calls while in the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thankfully this is not supported in any way. A 3rd party app has no control at a all over how a phone call is handled.

This might be possible on a jailbroken device using private APIs, but certainly not for an App Store app running on normal devices.

Comment: That makes sense, I guess Apple needs to draw a bottom line on what developers can and cannot do.